# What's the use of getters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, getter-setter

Why use getters instead of normal functions in JavaScript? Because they perform the exact same thing. What are the differences between a getter and a normal function in JavaScript?

Comment: Uh, can you show how you can achieve with a normal function what a getter does?

Comment: for `abstraction/encapsulation`.

Answer (score 1):

The get syntax binds an object property to a function that will be called when that property is looked up.

```
const obj = {
  log: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  get latest() {
    if (this.log.length == 0) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return this.log[this.log.length - 1];
  }
}

console.log(obj.latest);
// expected output: "c"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get